# Error: user does not have sufficient privileges to be assigned

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have three custom entities; `Project`, `ProjectStageExternal` and `ProjectStageInternal`,I have added a workflow which will create `ProjectStageInternal` and `ProjectStageExternal` records when admin creates a `Project` record.

Now I have a security roll named `customer`. Users having this roll only read the `Project` and `ProjectStageExternal` records.

[image]

The problem is workflow is not working when ownership is changed to users having  `customer` security roll. Its showing this following error: `The selected user does not have sufficient privileges to be assigned records of this type.`

what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: What entity are you assigning to the user? What sort of relationship is there between project and the stage-entities? I there's parental between project and projectstageinternal you will get an assign of the projectstateinternal object when you assign the project. That might be the culprit.

Comment: yes. I have 1:N parental between `Project` and `ProjectStageExternal`;also same between `Project` and `ProjectStageInternal`

Comment: Noh Rickard, I just changed the relationship to referential still I m getting the same error...

Comment: If you change owner of the project record to another user that is admin, does the owner of the stage-objects change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That security role has basically no permissions on those entities, so the users wont be able to do anything with them.

If you want someone to be able to assign (or have a workflow assign on their behalf) you need to grant the assign permission and probably write as well.

If you dont want to grant them those permissions, change the workflow's Scope to organisation and assign it to an admin user. That means the workflow will run with the admins permissions and security roles.

Comment: Scope is set to Organization. But, how can I assign a workflow to a admin user? The owner of this workflow is Admin.

Comment: Then its already assigned to the admin. What permissions does the admin have, also how is the workflow run?

Answer (score 1):

Only providing Read Privileges to the user/team whom the record is to be assigned will work perfectly fine !!